# Native Swift Dictionary by Reference

Tags: swift, dictionary

What I'm trying to do:

- a class that has several (say 10) instance variables of dictionary type (mutable `var`).
- a method that (depending on arguments, etc.) picks a dictionary an updates it.

In ObjC, this is fairly easily accomplished using `NSMutableDictionary`. In Swift, this is more tricky, since the dictionary gets copied on into the local variable.

I think the best way to explain what I'm trying to achieve is via a code sample:

```
class MyClass {

    /// There are several dictionaries as instance variables
    var dict1: [String : String] = [ : ]
    var dict2: [String : String] = [ : ]
    // ...

    /// This method should change a value in one of the dictionaries,
    /// depending on the argument.
    func changeDictAtIndex(index: Int) {
        var dict: [String : String]
        if index == 0 {
            dict = dict1
        }else{
            dict = dict2
        }
        dict["OK"] = "KO"

        // This won't work since Swift copies the dictionary into
        // the local variable, which gets destroyed at the end of
        // the scope...
    }

}

let obj = MyClass()
obj.changeDictAtIndex(0)
obj.dict1 // Still empty.
```

**Question:** Is there a **native** way to do this (native meaning **without** using `NSMutableDictionary`)?

P.S.: I'm aware of the `inout` attribute, but that works AFAIK only with function arguments, which doesn't really solve anything...

EDIT:

I'm currently solving this via closure:

```
var dictSetter: (key: String, value: String) -> Void
if index == 0 {
    dictSetter = { self.dict1[$0] = $1 }
}else{
    dictSetter = { self.dict2[$0] = $1 }
}

dictSetter(key: "OK", value: "KO")
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may already aware, you can use `inout` to solve the problem

```
func updateDict(inout dict: [String : String]) {
    dict["OK"] = "KO"
}

func changeDictAtIndex(index: Int) {
    if index == 0 {
        updateDict(&dict1)
    }else{
        updateDict(&dict2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that crossed my mind - as I mention in the question, I'm aware of `inout` attribute, just wanted to know if this can be solved without creating another method. I make some calculations within that method and only at the very end, it is known which dictionary will be updated with which value - which makes it slightly uglier than the ObjC variant...

Comment: I've currently solved this via closures (see my updated question).

Answer (score 0):

***Question: Is there a native way to do this (native meaning without using NSMutableDictionary)?***

I have rewritten your class, note the changes:

- Different syntax for empty dictionary
- ChangeDictAtIndex function now takes in a dictionary you want to replace.
- The instance variables are being set to the passed in dict.

I would look at the Apple's [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) section on the basics and collection types.

```
    class MyClass  {
        // There are several dictionaries as instance variables
        var dict1 = [String : String]()
        var dict2 = [String : String]()


        func changeDictAtIndex(index: Int, dict: [String : String]) {

            if index == 0 {
                dict1 = dict
            } else {
                dict2 = dict
            }
        }

    }
```

Usage:

```
let obj = MyClass()
obj.changeDictAtIndex(0, dict: ["MyKey" : "MyValue"])
print(obj.dict1)
```

Comment: Ad the syntax - there is no difference AFAIK - the type of the variable implies that it's not NSDictionary (which is the default type for `[ : ]`) and when inspected, the variables are indeed empty native Swift dictionary. It is my personal preference to have it the way I wrote it - it's a valid syntax. Ad the method: I can, of course, change the signature of the method, but that doesn't answer my question. I guess it's not possible to have a locally stored reference to a mutable Swift dictionary.

Comment: I am not saying what you wrote is not valid syntax, I was just listing the change I had made.